# How do I redefine target "clean"?

Tags: cmake

My CMmake build script includes an "external native makefile". Target-all has a dependency with an "external make". This dependency is made by CMake.

```
CMakeLists.txt
       |____( add_custom_target )_____ GNU make file
```

But Target-clean doesn't have a dependency with an "external make clean". I can't make dependency clean - external make clean. I can make a new custom-target (for example, newClean), and it has a dependency with "clean" and "external make clean". But "clean" and "newClean"  exist. It may be the confusion.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

There are three possible solutions I can think of:

1. Make sure all output files from custom commands are listed in the OUTPUT line. They will then be removed as part of clean (this behaviour is mentioned with the [`CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_dir:CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM) property).
2. Add extra files to the [`ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_dir:ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES) directory property.
3. Create a new custom command which calls the normal clean target and your other make file. Example:

   ```
   add_custom_target(really-clean
     COMMAND "$(CMAKE)" --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" clean
     COMMAND cd "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/otherproject" && make clean
   )
   ```

Comment: legacy build system is too big to resolve by 1 and 2. I try to choice option 3. even if it isn't clear. thank you..

Comment: The command listed didn't seem to run the normal clean correctly; using ''' COMMAND ${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} clean ''' worked for me.